# Printing google maps in black and white

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

A lot of my clients(companies) want to print google maps (with directions) on b/w printers. But when we tried to do this - maps became agly because google maps has litle contrast and small resolution. As a result  -  everething on map  isn't clear visible. We tried all possible settings of the printer and nothing couldnt help.
How to solve this programly? How make google maps (with routs on it) contrast ang good resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the [Styled Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) section of the Google Maps API. They even have a wizard that could help you create a grayscale map.

Comment: Yes. I have example of grayscale map: http://maps-api-tt.appspot.com/apilite/styled/styled.html . But the problem is that we using maps.google.com to make directions from one point to other and than print it with webBrowser control. If i will make style map i need to do copy of google directions web service by myself... that is a lot of work...

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer but something that indirectly solved the problem for me.
Overview - use freeware image editor 'IrfanView' to 'flatten' the image to b/w, using a custom threshold (not supported in standard IrfanView).

1. copy the map image from Google maps to the clipboard
2. paste into IrfanView
3. install the free 'threshold' plugin into IrfanView
   3.1) Download FineThreshold from http://www.mehdiplugins.com/english/finethreshold.htm
   3.2) Unzip it and save it in a known location.
   3.3) In IrfanView, go to Image / Adobe 8BF Plugins / Filter Dialogs.
   Use 'Add 8BF filters' (file) to locate and load the filter.
4. Use 'start selected filter' to invoke the actual filter.
   Note the 'ok/cancel' buttons remain grayed out but work.
5. I found ~228 was a good threshold value for Google Maps. Just slide around that mark, and see when the background switches from black to white. You have to hit 'ok' for each value to see the impact. Then you have to exit the plugin to return to the main IrfanView window.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.openstreetmap.org , select cycle map (on stack top right). Labels are slightly bigger than on Google, contrast is better (still not great)

Answer (score -1):

this looks better fit for your need

https://snazzymaps.com/style/79/black-and-white

you can print with markers and labels also.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32835334)